# Bootstrap4 vertical align two rows in container

Tags: html

I'm trying to get three buttons in the center of my container, after trying countless bootstrap classes I'm unable to achieve what should be simple.
The buttons are now horizontaly centered at the top.
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QxyQ.jpg)

the code looks like so :

```
<section>
<div id="video-play" class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="#" class="video" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=wKc5SSzB4xY" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#videoModal">
            <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get those buttons to align vertically in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just reorganize your content. Hope it helps.
What i've done first is to define a `style` into your video `div` *(as bootstrap recomands it)* to set a `height`.

Then you can use the class `.h-100` to let your content takes the full available height.

I use also the `flex-column` to organize the content : 1st, the `<i>`, 2nd the buttons.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
<div id="video-play" class="container-fluid" style="height:300px; background:yellow;">
    <div class="row h-100 text-center">
        <div class="col h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <a href="#" class="video mb-4" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=wKc5SSzB4xY" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#videoModal">
            <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you @bep42, the code you provided does exactly what I was looking for.
Something remains mysterious about the style you added in the <div> id="video-play"</div> as I had a min-height: 550px; on a separate stylesheet, I dont really understand why I have to keep your style in the div and the style I have on the separate stylesheet doesn't achieve the same result but anyways, it's working.
Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, I invite you to check the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent) you'll understand that `h-*` is relative to parent div. It means, you have to declare a height for the first parent div. And please if you're happy with the solution, could you validate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create 3 different div and in each one you have to put a button and center them with the tag center

```
<div><button>1</button></div>
<div><button>2</button></div>
<div><button>3</button></div>
```

every div must be as wide as the page!
I recommend you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

The code below should place both buttons under each other.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="video-play" class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="#" class="video" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=wKc5SSzB4xY" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#videoModal">
            <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
               <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
               </div>
               <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) for more documentation